# General formula of recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The recursively defined sequence given by:

a<sub>1</sub>=3, a<sub>k+1</sub>=4a<sub>k</sub>+1 for all k≥1

First 6 terms of the sequence are 3, 13, 53, 213, 853, 3413

I need help in finding the general formula of the sequence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get much better response if you format your posts in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{k+1}=4a_k+1$

$a_{k}=4a_{k-1}+1$

subtract:

$a_{k+1}-a_k=4a_k-4a_{k-1}$

$a_{k+1}=5a_k-4a_{k-1}$

Characteristic equation is $x^2-5x+4=0.$  Roots are $x=1$ and $4$, so $a_k=A+B4^n$.

Use your knowledge of $a_1$ and $a_2$ to solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Cf. [this](http://oeis.org/A072197)